# Part::partd: Part specification is longer than depth of object (Simple list)

Tags: functions, index, indexing

I know that this question has already been asked (I searched for answers), but in every thread I saw the code was much more complicated than what I'm trying to do, and I can't understand why this doesn't seem to work for me.

I was trying to define a simple function with variable index, just to start practicing with Mathematica, and this error started showing up.
I then tried to use the part in the easiest way possible but it still won't work!
[image]

Is there something I'm missing? I'm really new to Mathematica, but I didn't think I could already have problems with something apparently so simple! Thank you.

Comment: Are you doing something special to get the orange equal sign beside your input?  When you start typing, does it do that by default or do you start every input by typing "="?

Comment: it works for me. Why are calling wolfram Alpha in there? it does not remember previous variables. do not type `=` at start of the cell. Stay inside Mathematica.

Comment: I replicated the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCfVK.png) . Do not use a double `==` sign. `Set` uses a single `=` sign. In other languages, it is called 'assignment'.

Comment: @Nasser it is not strictly true that Alpha does not remember variables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cqGE.png but you have to use a specific syntax

Comment: Also, notice the difference between `Equal` (`==`) and `Set` (`=`). Wolfram Alpha is interpreting "=" as `Equal`.

Comment: Your question may be [closed](https://goo.gl/jXYaiD) as it seems to be [off-topic](https://goo.gl/bnZVrD), i.e it arises from a simple mistake (syntax error, incorrect capitalization, spelling mistake) and is unlikely to help any future visitors, or else it is easily found in the documentation. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning up policy. Your future [good questions](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](https://goo.gl/XAcNDp).

Comment: welcome to MMA and MMA SE! just checking—did the comments above make it directly clear what's happening? you're calling wolfram alpha (the orange equals sign) each time instead of typing mathematica input, maybe by pressing `=` before typing, instead of simply typing your mathematica input. if you just start typing e.g. `x = {1,2,3}`, you should be fine. [Here's what it should look like.](https://imgur.com/GSr8ZCE) Also check the docs ("help" in the top right of each window), and have fun!